# Is "panko" a common word?

Tags: nouns, word-usage

I recently found the word *panko* [in a dictionary](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/panko). It is derived from the Japanese word "パン粉" and means bread crumbs.

Is *panko* a common word in English? For example, can I ask supermarket staff "Where is panko"?

Comment: The boxes are generally labeled "panko bread crumbs" or "panko flakes", so the manufacturers don't trust English speakers to know what "panko" is. I don't know what the supermarket staff calls them. And they are ***not*** just bread crumbs; they are Japanese-style bread crumbs. Supermarkets also sell bread crumbs which aren't panko.

Comment: I haven't heard of it.

Comment: This is the 1st time I heard of the word.

Comment: Common in urban California.  I can't imagine a supermarket manager who wouldn't know what panko is.  There are even generic store brands that mimic the major brands.  There are also hybrid styles – like “Italian Style Panko” that has the Japanese style light flaky breadcrumbs but with Italian seasoning added.  I'd say it's very common; but only in the last 10 years or so.  Before that you'd probably have to go to an Asian specialty store to get the breading for right-and-proper tempura, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same link also mentions "the Japanese variety of bread crumbs is called panko", which means not all bread crumbs are called *panko*, and it's not a common word in English.

Answer (score 3):

[Panko breadcrumbs](http://www.ifood.tv/network/panko) are Japanese-style breadcrumbs and are known well among anyone who cooks regularly, though it may not be a common word among people who don't cook. The popularity of cooking shows has made them much [more well-known in recent years](https://suite.io/mary-king/1jvn25t), though.

[Alton Brown on Panko](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwFYVDTl4nA)

Comment: Unfortunately the movie was blocked and I could not watch it. But seems a popular one.Thanks.